# Cannot get Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition to create a new Django project

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2015

Title says it all, using a relatively vanilla Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, I can't make a new Django project from the "File > New Project..." menu.

Thus far the only additions I've made are installing the Python 2.7.10 runtime, as recommended my Microsoft, and then installed django via pip inside Visual Studio. But I keep getting the error below:

> ```
> ---------------------------
> Microsoft Visual Studio
> ---------------------------
> The project file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\4wdsrkia.hmh\Temp\DjangoWebProject1.pyproj'
> cannot be opened.
>
> There is a missing project subtype.
> Subtype: '{5F0BE9CA-D677-4A4D-8806-6076C0FAAD37}' is unsupported by this installation.
> ---------------------------
> OK   Help   
> ---------------------------
> ```

Any tips?

<sub>For those wondering, if you type <kbd>Crtl+C</kbd> while a dialog has focus, it makes a pretty ASCII version of the dialog for pasting.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one got solved by testing out making a Flask project which had a much more helpful error message about needing the 'Web tools installed'.

So, after closing Visual Studio, opening the control panel, modifying the Visual Studio to include the "Web Developer tools", waiting for it to install, and reopening Visual Studio it worked fine!

[image]